# How to prevent my JNI C code from exiting while the JVM it launched is still running a Java thread?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm writing a C++ application that will rely on another **embedded** Java application. The barebones of my C++ application is below. My question is *how do I prevent it from exiting while the JVM is running my thread above?*

```
#include <jni.h>

int main()
{
       Using namespace std;
       JavaVM *jvm;                      // Pointer to the JVM (Java Virtual Machine)
       JNIEnv *env;                      // Pointer to native interface
           //================== prepare loading of Java VM ============================
       JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;                        // Initialization arguments
       JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];   // JVM invocation options
       options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=.";   // where to find java .class
       vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;             // minimum Java version
       vm_args.nOptions = 1;                          // number of options
       vm_args.options = options;
       vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;     // invalid options make the JVM init fail
           //=============== load and initialize Java VM and JNI interface =============
       jint rc = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);  // YES !!
       delete options;    // we then no longer need the initialisation options. 
       if (rc != JNI_OK) {
              // TO DO: error processing... 
             cin.get();
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }
          //=============== Display JVM version =======================================
       cout << "JVM load succeeded!\n";

        // HERE I'LL CALL A STATIC METHOD ON A JAVA CLASS THAT WILL START A JAVA THREAD
        // What do I do here to keep my C application running while the JVM has my thread running?

       jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
}
```

Source: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/993067/Calling-Java-from-Cplusplus-with-JNI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can get hold of a reference to an instance of `CallbackFromJava`, you can just call `thread.join()` on it:

```
jobject cbfj = ...;
jclass cls_cbfj = env->GetObjectclass(cbfj);
jfieldID fid_cbfj_thread = env->GetFieldID(cls_cbfj, "thread", "Ljava/lang/Thread;");
jobject thread = env->GetObjectField(cbfj, fid_cbfj_thread);

jclass cls_thread = env->GetObjectClass(thread);
jmethodID mid_thread_join = env->GetMethodID(cls_thread, "join", "()V");
env->CallVoidMethod(thread, mid_thread_join);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm surprised by its simplicity. What about that attachCurrentThread and dettachCurrentThread madness? Do I need to worry about that in that situation? When do I have to worry about that?

Comment: Threads are "attached" to the JVM either because they started it or because they are explicitly attached. Since your main thread started the JVM you should not worry about attaching.

Comment: If my Java thread calls back my C++ thread, do I need to attach it? Probably, right?

Comment: By "call back" you mean invoking the `hiFromJava` method? No. Invocations of JNI methods happen on the same (Java) thread.

Comment: Yes, the `hiFromJava` is the callback. I'm having a hard time imagining the scenario were `attachCurrentThread` is actually needed it. My Java thread calling `hiFromJava` was never attached by the JVM in the C++ side, correct? Why it does not need to be attached? If this Java thread then creates another thread, then it needs to be attached? We have three threads here: the main C thread that started the JVM, the Java thread, and the Java thread created by the Java thread.

Comment: Any thread created by Java is automatically considered to be attached. The only time when you need to attach manually is when you have created a new OS thread from outside Java and want to retrieve a `JNIEnv*` to interact with it.

Answer (score 0):

[`DestroyJavaVM`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/specs/jni/invocation.html#destroyjavavm) will wait until all non-daemon threads are joined:

> This function waits until all non-daemon threads have terminated, excluding the current thread if it is non-daemon, and then initiates the shutdown sequence (see java.lang.Runtime)

So, your code should already work as is. (assuming you didn't make the thread daemon)

Comment: !!!!!!!?????? Thanks for noting that :) I worried about something I should not be worried about :)